# What's the minimum hearing loss that hearing aids can treat considering that subclinical hearing loss may increase the risk of dementia?

Tags: alzheimers, dementia, audiology, hearing-aids, hearing-loss

It's important to treat hearing loss when it comes to brain function. There's research showing that the risk of dementia may increase two-fold when it's mild, three-fold when it's moderate, and five-fold when it's severe.

Even with subclinical hearing loss which is below 25 dB, a study found that those participants had reduced cognitive performance, which suggests that they may benefit from using hearing aids.
https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaotolaryngology/fullarticle/2755646

What's the lowest hearing loss that they can treat?

If someone has 10 dB of hearing loss, would they simply amplify the quietest speech sounds by 10 dB so that they can hear speech as well as those without any hearing loss?

Comment: Be careful about mixing correlation with causation: https://xkcd.com/552/ An association between hearing loss and dementia does not mean that correcting hearing loss would prevent the associated dementia risk. There could be confounding with other exposures, or hearing loss could be a surrogate marker of brain aging.

Comment: I agree that we should be careful before drawing conclusions but there's also research showing that those with corrected hearing loss have a 19% lower risk of cognitive decline. Hearing aids also improve cognitive scores. You can also try listening to audio at a volume that you can barely hear. You'll feel how much straining you need to hear.
https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/could-treating-hearing-loss-reduce-the-risk-of-dementia

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Hearing aids can treat any degree of hearing loss, including 100%. What's important is the _cause_ of the hearing loss, not the degree. Hearing loss can be due to conductive problems in the middle ear, cochlear damage, or neural problems. A hearing aid can't do anything for neural hearing loss, but there are hearing aids that can transmit sounds from one side to the other if only one side suffers loss. Cochlear implants can help with cochlear hearing loss. So I would recommend you learn more about hearing loss, hearing aids, and cochlear implants.